# Word to describe a lover of nature, particularly flowers

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word to describer a character's personality.
A trait, if you will.

The character in question is

1. extremely **fond of nature**,
2. but, he's **not exactly an outdoorsman** - no camping, very little hiking, and such.
3. He **enjoys to observe nature**, likes to draw nature scenes, and
4. He's **particularly fond of flowers**.
5. He does **like gardening and keeps an impressive garden**,
6. but other than that **does not spend large amounts of time interacting with nature itself**.
7. He also **works as a florist** - as my attempt to cement his

   > **favoritism of flowers**.

Can anybody supply me with a word that could sort of cover this type of personality? It doesn't have to be exactly spot on as that might border on impossible, but a word that is at least similar and might cover with some additional explanation.

Comment: From the [info about the single-word-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info): This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.  Also, you probably want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: Why does 'nature-lover' not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have listed multiple traits of the person and some of them are contrasting. There is no particular word that describes all the qualities in a person at the same time: `enjoys to observe nature, does not like to go out, He does like gardening and keeps an impressive garden, and favoritism of flowers etc.,`

Out of these traits, I'll address the trait which you are most interested about:

`1. favoritism of flowers`:

The word that can be found in standard dictionaries like Oxford online dictionary is:

[**anthomania**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anthomania)

> Excessive or passionate enthusiasm for flowers.

So, the person can be called anthomaniac.

Internet slang for a person fond of flower is **anthophile**. According to Oxford, anthophile actually means

> An insect which is typically found on flowers, or which feeds from flowers.